# Iterative sequence converging

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider the sequence

> $$1^4,2^4,3^4,\ldots,k^4,\ldots$$

Form a new sequence, whose terms consist of the difference of the above sequence.

> $$2^4-1^4,3^4-2^4,4^4-3^4,\ldots$$

Repeat the process with the terms of *this* new sequence. When this is done sufficiently many times, you will eventually get the sequence

> $$24, 24, 24, 24, \ldots$$

Why is this the case fundamentally, from a mathematical perspective? Why 24 exactly? I suspect it might have something to do with the fact that $24 = 4!$, though this could be completely off. Will it still work if we used the same algorithm with any arbitrary exponent $n$ instead of $4$? I can not answer this question because I can't seem to formalize this process in a way that allows me to see obvious convergence to a constant sequence.

Comment: if $f(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ with leading coefficient $1$, then $f(x+1)-f(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n-1$ with leading coefficient $n$. If you start from a polynomial of degree $n$ with leading coefficient $1$ and taking such a [finite difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference) $n$ times. you get $n!$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the *calculus of finite differences*. You are starting
with a function $f(x)$ (here $f(x)=x^4$) and defining a new one by $g(x)=f(x+1)-f(x)$, then iterating the procedure.

In general if $f(x)=a_nx^n+\cdots+a_0$ is a polynomial of degree $n$,
then $g(x)=na_nx^{n-1}+\cdots$ is also a polynomial. Iterating then gives
$n(n-1)a_n x^{n-2}+\cdots$ and after $n$ stages we get the constant
$n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots 1a_n$.